# Returning a php element with a count with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, count

I have a site where people search for music and the search is recorded with their id attached to it. I am trying to make a feed out of it and it has worked thus far. However, the feed includes a javascript function where it makes their search into a link which when clicked, populates the search field and completes the search. The problem is I am looking to make each link it's specific search, but what ends up happening is it sets the value of the php variable to the last search in the array. What I'm now trying to do is set the php search variable with an counter to call that later in javascript. I know this sounds super confusing / not clear, but I'm trying my best. Maybe the code will help.

```
    $sql_userSearch = mysql_query("SELECT id, searchstring, timecount, userSearch FROM trending WHERE userSearch != 0 ORDER BY timecount DESC LIMIT 50");


    $counter = 1; 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_userSearch)){

$search_id = $row["id"];
$searcher_id = $row["userSearch"];
$the_search[$counter] = $row["searchstring"];
$search_date = $row["timecount"];
$convertedTime = ($myObject -> convert_datetime($search_date));
$whenSearch = ($myObject -> makeAgo($convertedTime));
$search_date = $row["timecount"];


$searchDisplayList .= 
'<table style="border:#999 1px solid; border-top:none;" background="img/searchBG.png" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
 <tr>
    <td width="10%" valign="top"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'. $searcher_id . '/picture" width="35" height="35"></td>
    <td width="90%" valign="top" style="line-height:1.5em;">
    <span class="liteGreyColor textsize9"><strong>' . $searcher_id . '</strong></a> searched for </span>
    <a href="#" onClick="swapSearch()">' . $the_search[$counter] . '</a></br> ' . $whenSearch . ' 
    </td>
    </tr></table>';


$counter++;
}
```

then later on, this is the javascript I am using to return the link.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function swapSearch(){
        document.getElementById('s').value = "<?= $the_search[$counter] ?>";
        $('#searchForm').submit();  
    }
    </script>
```

EDIT:

I just ended up using some javascript that grabbed the text of the link and populated the search form. Way easier than what I was trying to do.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $("a.friendSearchLink").live("click",function(a) {       
a.preventDefault();                         
var searchTerm = $(this).text();
document.getElementById('s').value = searchTerm;
$("#searchForm").submit();                  
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The "link" text of the javascript shows up correctly, however, when you click the link, it doesn't populate the search with the right text.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is preprocessed, you can only echo a value prior to the page being sent to your client. In  order to do what you're wanting to do, you must send an ajax call to a page that contains the information you're looking for, otherwise your output will be completely static.

Comment: ok so say I json encode the output and grab it with ajax. How can I get each link to match up with it's corresponding element in the array?

Comment: A json array is JavaScript native, you can use jQuery's `$.getJSON` function to grab the object, then just iterate through the object.

Answer (score 0):

you could store all the searches from `$the_search` into a JS array and then pass in `$counter` to `swapSearch('.$counter.')`. then you can look up in js whatever the search is.

The only other question I have though is are you submitting your search form as a post? Because if you change it to read from $_GET, you can just use the link to run the search just by setting `href="?q=$the_search[$counter]"`. Other option is to pass the search id in the url and just use php to load the search result/keywords.